# SQL query where parameters null not null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I am trying to do a SQL query and to build the where condition dynamically depending if the parameters are null or no. I have something like this:

```
SELECT tblOrder.ProdOrder, tblOrder.Customer FROM tblOrder 
CASE WHEN @OrderId IS NOT NULL
THEN 
WHERE tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId
ELSE
END
CASE WHEN @OrderCustomer IS NOT NULL
THEN
AND tblOrder.OrderCustomer = @OrderCustomer
ELSE
END
END
```

This doesn't work, but this is just a small prototype how to assemble the query, so if the orderid is not null include in the where clause, or if the ordercustomer is not null include in the where clause. But I see problem here, for example if the ordercustomer is not null but the orderid is null, there will be error because the where keyword is not included.

How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT tblOrder.ProdOrder, tblOrder.Customer 
FROM tblOrder 
WHERE ( @OrderId IS NULL OR  tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId )
AND   ( @OrderCustomer IS NULL OR  tblOrder.OrderCustomer = @OrderCustomer )
OPRION (RECOMPILE)
```

But as commented you should include the OPTION RECOMPILE hint, otherwise it will have bad performance.

Worth reading:

- http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: [But have poor performance unless `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is used](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: This works, but it cannot leverage indexes.  Dynamic SQL with `sp_ExecuteSql` is probably a better choice, in general, for this kind of problem, as Gail Shaw explains here: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @MartinSmith (noob side question): how do you embed your link within text like that in a comment?  I can't edit other people's comments, so I can't figure out how they do it...

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically write the `WHERE` clause, but you can use compound statements to achieve the desired effect.
Since in SQL `NULL` is **never** equal to any value, you can actually achieve a pretty elegant query:

```
SELECT tblOrder.ProdOrder, tblOrder.Customer 
FROM   tblOrder 
WHERE  
-- Can only be true if @OrderId isn't NULL, no need to state it explicitly
tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId 
OR 
-- Thanks to short-circuit evaluation, 
-- we only get here if the first condition evaluated as false
tblOrder.OrderCustomer = @OrderCustomer
```

Comment: If the parameters are NULL they shoul be ignored in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

This query is completely wrong. After formatting you can see that there are "blank" `ELSE` statements, and you have extra `END` at the end :):

```
SELECT 
    tblOrder.ProdOrder, tblOrder.Customer 
FROM tblOrder 
CASE 
    WHEN @OrderId IS NOT NULL THEN WHERE tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId
    ELSE 
END
CASE 
    WHEN @OrderCustomer IS NOT NULL THEN AND tblOrder.OrderCustomer = @OrderCustomer
    ELSE 
END
END
```

Besides you can't return `WHERE` clause from `CASE`.

Use this instead. It's much more simple, and it works ;).

```
SELECT 
    tblOrder.ProdOrder, tblOrder.Customer 
FROM tblOrder 
where
    tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId
    OR 
    tblOrder.OrderCustomer = @OrderCustomer
```

You don't even have to worry about both variables being `NULL`, if you have `ANSI_NULLS` set. By default Sql Server won't match records, where `NULL=NULL`.

Comment: Ignores the fact that the parameters can be NULL in which case they should be ignored in the filter.